# Function to calculate the ordinal day

Tags: beginner, c, datetime, homework

I just handed in my first assessed coursework for my Computer Science degree. Part of it was to take in a date (`dd mm yyyy`) between 1900 and 2100 and output the ordinal date. My function to do that is below.

I’m new to C - I’ve used Python, JavaScript and more recently Pascal, so I might be approaching this from the wrong direction, and there could be a more traditional method I should be using.

Any suggestions to make this more standard with C guidelines would be great - in addition to other algorithms I could have used.

```
int monthToDays(int day, int month, int year) {
  int monthLengths[11] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30}; // only 11 long because january -> 0 not 31

  monthLengths[1] = monthLengths[1] + checkIsLeap(year); //increase febuaray by 1 if it's a leap year

  int iMonth = 0;
  int totalDays = day;
                          // reduce by 1 because array is 0 indexed
  for (iMonth = 0; iMonth < month - 1; iMonth++) {
    totalDays = totalDays + monthLengths[iMonth];
  }

  return totalDays;
}
```

```
int checkIsLeap(int year) {

  int leap = 0;

  if (year % 4 == 0) {
    leap = 1;
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
      leap = 0;
      if (year % 400 == 0) {
        leap = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return leap;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `checkIsLeap` for completeness?

Comment: @Phrancis it’s pretty basic - returns 1 if the year given is a leap year.

Comment: You could save a trivial amount of time by keeping track of the sum of days in given months: `{31, 59, 89, ...}`, and changing your leap year test slightly.

Comment: @BarryCarter yeah, in hindsight that’s a much nicer way - although the leap year test is more complex.

Comment: `if (checkIsLeap(year) && month > 2) {totalDays++}` should do it. Extreme nitpick: if your date is guaranteed to be between 1901 and 2099 (you said 1900 and 2100), the leap year test is simpler (`year%4` no exceptions). However, your code is more general which is good.

Comment: Be careful with your coding contract: "between 1900 and 2100" --> does that include the end years? - it is a bit ambiguous.  In this learning exercise, of course it should  include the end years, yet with production code and goals, better to be specific:  "between 1900 and 2100 inclusive" or "[1900 ... 2100]" or  `1900 <= year <= 2100", etc.

Answer (score 2):

## Remarks about your code

- I, too, think that you should change the signature and *not* pass the year into that function, since basically it doesn't need to know about the year.  What it *needs* to know is whether it's a leap year or not (thus a `bool` from [`stdbool.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean)).  So pass that in. (A bit like [`Tell, don't ask`](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) in OOP)
- Modifying the months length of February seems like the most "real world like" approach, but I wouldn't do it, because then you can make the months lengths `const` (and also `static`).  Do a correction (`+ 1`) for leap years after your calculation, then.
- Going further, are you really interested in the lengths of a month? You could as well just store the number of days (in a non leap year) that precede a month (January -> `0`, February -> `31`, March -> `31 + 28`, ...).  Then you can get rid of that loop all together.
- Lack of [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert)ments: When you make an assumption about the value of an function argument (`1 <= months <= 12`), then `assert` for that (even if the specification of your function does not include argument validation!) such that *if* an invalid value gets passed, you fail fast and loud. (*Ooops .. an advise I should have implemented myself in the code below ...*)
- naming. `monthToDays` ... sounds like "convert a month into days" ... I would expect this to accept a month (number) and get the number of days in that month. `ordinal_date` ? Or a bit more detailed `ordinal_date_day` ?

## Test, test, test!

Next, I'd like to introduce you to [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (test driven development): Instead of first writing your code and then test it (as all - or almost all - code should be tested!) you start off writing tests, specifying the desired behavior, and then make these tests pass by actually implementing the logic to achieve that behavior.

Normally, you'd look into some testing framework / library, but we can go with a simple macro here for now:

```
#define check(expr) \
  if(!(expr)) { \
    printf("[FAILED] " #expr " in %s\n", __func__); \
  }
```

Note that this is the bare minimum of information we need out of a test case: An indication when it fails and which test case failed.  Testing frameworks can give you far better information, for example a comparison of the expected value of a function call and it's actual value.

Start with a simple case:

```
void ordinal_date_in_january_should_be_day_number() {
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 1, false) ==  1);
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 1,  true) ==  1);
  check(ordinal_date(11, 1, false) == 11);
  check(ordinal_date(11, 1,  true) == 11);
}
```

That's simple to implement:

```
int ordinal_date(int day, int month, bool leap_year) {
  return day;
}
```

Going to a slightly more complex case, days in February:

```
void ordinal_date_in_february_should_be_day_number_plus_days_in_january() {
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 2, false) == 32);
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 2,  true) == 32);
  check(ordinal_date(11, 2, false) == 42);
  check(ordinal_date(11, 2,  true) == 42);
}
```

Well, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#In_software_development):

```
int ordinal_date(int day, int month, bool leap_year) {
  if (month == 1) {
    return day;
  }
  if (month == 2) {
    return day + 31;
  }
  return -1; // Fall-through, always code defensively
}
```

Fine, tests pass again.  Time for new tests.  Check against [known values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date):

```
void ordinal_date_should_match_known_values_for_non_leap_year_march_to_dezember() {
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  3, false) == ( 59 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  4, false) == ( 90 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  5, false) == (120 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  6, false) == (151 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  7, false) == (181 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  8, false) == (212 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  9, false) == (243 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 10, false) == (273 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 11, false) == (304 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 12, false) == (334 + 1));
}
```

Ok, we can go on with these `if` .. but this starts to look like a lookup table to me, so better implement that instead:

```
int ordinal_date(int day, int month, bool leap_year) {
  static const int days_up_to_month[] = {
    0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334};
  return days_up_to_month[month - 1] + day;
}
```

Note that we can make this change with confidence of *not* breaking existing requirements due to the previous tests we wrote.

Finally, let's include the known values for a leap year:

```
void ordinal_date_should_match_known_values_for_leap_year_march_to_dezember() {
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  3, true) == ( 60 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  4, true) == ( 91 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  5, true) == (121 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  6, true) == (152 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  7, true) == (182 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  8, true) == (213 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1,  9, true) == (244 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 10, true) == (274 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 11, true) == (305 + 1));
  check(ordinal_date( 1, 12, true) == (335 + 1));
}
```

Of course this fails spectacularly, but is easily fixed with some "domain knowledge" (namely that in a leap year February is a day longer):

```
int ordinal_date(int day, int month, bool leap_year) {
  static const int days_up_to_month[] = {
    0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334};
  return days_up_to_month[month - 1] + day
         + ((leap_year && (month > 2)) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Note that our tests would have revealed this domain knowledge, too.  Try the code without the `month > 2` condition and see which tests fail.

Finally: Tests pass.  Fine.  I hope this is of potential use for you.

*([Ideone link](https://ideone.com/5rwzrf) with above code)*

---

- That `2` is a naked magic number, which is **not good**.  Better define a constant `FEB` or something like that.
- You wrote that the code is tested with 65000 random values.  Sorry, but **that's useless**.  For this example, it will - of course (with very high probability) - spot any errors in the implementation as there are only `365 + 366` different inputs that the function might take.  But what it won't help with is *clearly documenting* the desired behavior.  Moreover, running your test will take a lot more time than running the simpler tests here.  That's not an issue for just one function, but within a mid size to large size project these run times will build up quickly.  And the longer the test, the less often you will run it!  The less often you run it, the more code you write without testing it.

Comment: This looks great. Tears were done with a Gitlab yml file, which randomly tested 65,000 values. Other than that, the advice is great.

Comment: Minor: Avoid naked magic numbers: --> `+ ((leap_year && (month > FEB)) ? 1 : 0);` pr `+ (leap_year && (month > FEB));`

Comment: @chux Yep, good point, added.

Comment: @Tim I've added a comment about your tests :)

Comment: Testing 65,000 random values is not useless, just insufficient to certainly catch corner cases.  Testing only select cases is also insufficient to catch issues that are not covered.  Example: IMO: _any_ combination of `int` arguments should not seg fault.  Testing corner case, special values , some of the `365+366` [the usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To) and some random values makes for a robust test.

Comment: @chux it's not 5000 but 65000 ... and that's just a waste of time / computing resources.

Comment: Number corrected.  Agree about excessive-ness and its diminishing value.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than supplying `year`, you might have the caller pass in the result of `checkIsLeap()`. Six one way, half dozen the other.

It is important to pair this code with some unit test code which exercises it.

You might report errors if the caller passes invalid input values.

Otherwise, it looks good, ship it.

Comment: Yes, this code is checked with 65,000 random dates, generated by known good code.